# "NHibernate.StaleStateException: Unexpected row count: -1" on any update\insert into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

My app (ASP.NET web site) was working perfectly. Suddenly - without any app update\change - client started reporting errors (see exception message in the title) for operations executing INSERTs\UPDATEs. 
After a short investigation it was clear that **ANY UPDATE\INSERT query is failing** with similar message.

Client's IT department stated that no update\environment change happened neither on SQL Server or IIS server.

Any idea what happened ?

**Note:**
May look like duplicate question but its not. Most of the similar questions (exception messages) here are with "**expected: 0**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time researching this, here is an answer...

It seems 0+  in "expected" usually means "Row count returned from DML query was returned by SQL Server but was different from expected". On the other hand -1 means something like "SQL Server not returned row count at all"

I know you can use `SET NOCOUNT ON` on active connection to make SQL Server stop returning affected rows count but I don't use it for sure and without app change there is no way someone else can activate this option for my connection, right ?

**Wrong!** In fact there is something called "default user options" on SQL server as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-options-server-configuration-option). Can be changed in SQL Server MS or by sql script using `sp_configure`. Only admins can change that and it affects all users connections to all databases on single server instance. In my case, some admin changed default options to `NOCOUNT ON`. After reverting settings to its default value, app started working again...

HTH someone...